# Red sheen on texture paint

Tags: texturing, texture-painting

I'm not sure why, but there is a reddish sheen on my mesh whenever I texture paint. Sadly I won't be able to provide the blend file, but I can provide a picture of what it looks like. and some of my brush settings.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I figured out the problem, I had another material on that was affecting it.